# subtract minutes from datetime - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that consist of two columns:

- _time - dtype: datatime64
- elapsed - dtype: object

See the dataframe:

`vehicles_stats[['_time','elapsed']].head()`

Output:

```
    _time                               elapsed
0   2020-10-28 21:06:39.797000+01:00    26
1   2020-10-28 16:12:38.357000+01:00    16
2   2020-10-28 19:16:38.737000+01:00    11
3   2020-10-29 11:58:43.122000+01:00    16
4   2020-10-28 20:38:39.294000+01:00    16
```

How can I change the type of the "elapsed" column so that it represents minutes?
Then, I need to subtract these minutes from the _time value for each record.

Any advise appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_time']).sub(pd.to_timedelta(df['elapsed'], unit='min'))
print (df)
                              _time  elapsed                     new
0  2020-10-28 21:06:39.797000+01:00       26 2020-10-28 19:40:39.797
1  2020-10-28 16:12:38.357000+01:00       16 2020-10-28 14:56:38.357
2  2020-10-28 19:16:38.737000+01:00       11 2020-10-28 18:05:38.737
3  2020-10-29 11:58:43.122000+01:00       16 2020-10-29 10:42:43.122
4  2020-10-28 20:38:39.294000+01:00       16 2020-10-28 19:22:39.294
```

If need column convert to timedeltas from minutes:

```
df['elapsed'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['elapsed'], unit='min')
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_time']).sub(df['elapsed'])
print (df)
                              _time         elapsed                     new
0  2020-10-28 21:06:39.797000+01:00 0 days 00:26:00 2020-10-28 19:40:39.797
1  2020-10-28 16:12:38.357000+01:00 0 days 00:16:00 2020-10-28 14:56:38.357
2  2020-10-28 19:16:38.737000+01:00 0 days 00:11:00 2020-10-28 18:05:38.737
3  2020-10-29 11:58:43.122000+01:00 0 days 00:16:00 2020-10-29 10:42:43.122
4  2020-10-28 20:38:39.294000+01:00 0 days 00:16:00 2020-10-28 19:22:39.294
```